# Inserting commas to a number without using any utility methods

Tags: java, string, integer

I want to convert an Integer 35634646 to have commas ","(Indian locale) without using any utility APIs.

For ex, if my input is 12345,then output should be : 12,345 or if the input is 123456,output should be 1,23,456.

I cannot use any existing utility functions.

I need in Indian numbering format.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system

Comment: Have you the posibility to use java standard methods?

Comment: @PeterLawrey : I am not allowed to use any java standard methods and i am not able to create any logic.

Comment: @Jens :  No, i cannot use any standard methods.

Comment: @6190 Please be more specific as to what you can and can't use. You have to be able to use SOME standard methods, if only to print.

Comment: @KathyA.: I can use methods to print but i cannot use "NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(numToFormat)" or "NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance().format(numToFormat)" ; meaning i cannot use any standard method for formatting,there has to be my own logic.

Comment: @KathyA i assume that this is school work :p

What about print numbers, one by one. Using %.

Ex: number % 10 Will print the first number. number % 100 / 10 will print the second number ... etc

Comment: @RaNdoM_PoWneD: This is not any school work , it was asked in an interview.

Comment: Ok ;) What about my solution?

Comment: @6190 Then I suggest you look at the total length of the string, then loop through each character. If the remaining characters are evenly disvisble by 3, print a comma before the character. Let me know if you need more help than that. The documentation for String will tell you how to get the length of the string and how to access each character.

Comment: @6190 so can you use String.substring()?

Comment: @KathyA.: I need Indian numbering format.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes,i can use it.

Comment: @6190 In that case I would use the string.length() and string.substring() to get portions of the original string and add `","` in the right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maby not the best way, but i'm in hurry, and it works

```
    String s = "25467896743242";
    System.out.println(s.charAt(0));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    s = sb.reverse().toString();
    //int groupCount=4;
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        if ((i == 3) || i > 3 && i % 2 == 1) {
            sb.append(',');
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2,54,67,89,67,43,242
```

Comment: I need it in INDIAN format.So,the output should have been: 3,53,15,626.

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that. Answer is corrected, and fixed, so it will work with huge numbers as well.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should help you:

```
long l = 1234567;
String s = String.valueOf(l);

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int j=0;
for (int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
    if (j==3){
        sb.append(',');
        j=0;
    }
    sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    j++;
}

System.out.println(sb.reverse());
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've modified T.G's answer to do Indian format:

```
    private static void printNum(int number) {
    String s = number + "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    s = sb.reverse().toString();
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = s.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        if (i % 2 == 1 && i != 1)
            sb.append(',');
    }
    System.out.println(sb);
}
```

35315626 gives an output of 3,53,15,626